# cursor jumps in search form, garbles input while typing

Tags: bug, status-declined, search

Lately I was searching on tex.sx from the search form at the top of the page. After a first search, I positioned the cursor somewhere halfway in my previous search terms and started to type additional keywords. Upon automatic expansion of the search form, the cursor was placed at the end of my input, leaving the words I was typing garbled.

This is annoying, especially since it takes a second before the search form expands, so I'd have to wait for that time before editing my search terms.

I'm using Debian Iceweasel, the version string is:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686 (x86_64); en-US; rv:1.9.1.16) Gecko/20111108 Iceweasel/3.5.16 (like Firefox/3.5.16)
```

Comment: I just checked with a plain install of Firefox 9.0.1; then it works OK: the cursor position doesn't change when the search form is expanded.

Comment: Under Windows, running the latest version of Google Chrome (`16.0.912.63 m`), there is also *no* problem.

Comment: Does it happen in other sites from the SE network, say [math.sx](http://math.stackexchange.com/)? Maybe it's a general issue.

Comment: @Paulo: yes, same problem there, so indeed (as to be expected) this is a general SE websites issue. Should I report this somewhere else?

Answer (score 7):

We don't support old versions of Firefox (or any other browser, e.g. IE7), we always support the current version of a browser and the one before that. As of this answer, that includes:

- Firefox 9.0
- Firefox 8.0

3.5.16 is *quite* a bit out of date, we won't fix bugs related to it.

For more info: the community maintains a supported browser list here: [Which browsers are officially supported? And what else do I need?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need) (though even *that* isn't quite up to date, you can see we've long-since dropped support for 3.5)